# Как в Python проверить, свободен домен или нет?

Tags: python, python-3.x, whois

Мне нужно проверять, свободен домен или нет.
Подскажите функцию, которая принимает на вход имя домена, например "*ya.ru*", а на выходе выдает статус свободен домен `True` или занят `False`, ну или любую другую информацию о домене, из которой можно понять статус домена?

Ранее, в python2.7  я делал проверку через модуль `whois`

> whois.whois('google.com')

Но в python 3 это уже не работает, я получаю ошибки. Привожу скрины с ошибками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как насчет `import whois`?

Comment: на первом скрине у меня стоит `import whois`, не работает.
У вас получается? Можете в colab.research.google.com привести пример рабочего кода?

Comment: ну, давайте, вот, как. Что будет если посмотреть доступные имена и атрибуты `dir(whois)`? А, вы не увидите там `whois`, но обнаружите, например, `query`. И так, `m= whois.query('ya.ru')`. Ну, а, далее пишите условия и разбирайте. Например, `print(m.name)` будет выдавать имя домена.

Comment: Так и есть, `whois` в `dir(whois)` нет.
Выдаёт вот такое:
`['CACHE_FILE',
 'Domain',
 'FailedParsingWhoisOutput',
 'SLOW_DOWN',
 'TLD_RE',
 'UnknownDateFormat',
 'UnknownTld',
 'WhoisCommandFailed',
 '_1_query',
 '_2_parse',
 '_3_adjust',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'do_parse',
 'do_query',
 'exceptions',
 'query',
 'tld_regexpr']`

Comment: а при выполнении `m=whois.query('ya.ru')`  получаю вот такое сообщение: *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'whois': 'whois'*

Comment: Гляньте на ответ от @mrEvgenX вам дает понять что в вашей ОС нет утилиты `whois`.

Comment: @Дмитрий, вот тут я попробовал воспроизвести ваш код: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15bg9UCQeJq_SIRfL3Jnkq8X_yQsyl-Ur?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Модуль под капотом запускает консольную утилиту `whois` с помощью библиотеки `subprocess`.

Она скорее всего не установлена. Команда, которая должна помочь:

```
sudo apt-get install whois
```

а на windows поможет утилита [Whois v1.21](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/whois)

Comment: а если я работаю с windows или в colab.research.google.com , как тогда подключить `subprocess` ?

Comment: А такие обстоятельства все портят. К слову`subprocess`  - то стандартный встроенный модуль. А установить надо консольную утилиту `whois`. Если в консоли заработает `whois google.com`, тогда заработает и программа, написанная с использованием https://pypi.org/project/whois/...

Answer (score 0):

чтобы не качать под windows exeшник whois:

```
import socket
for dom in ['ya.ru', 'error.qwerty']:
    try:
        s = socket.getaddrinfo(dom, 80)
        print(f'занят {dom} {s}')
    except socket.gaierror:
        print(f'свободен {dom}')

# занят ya.ru [(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('87.250.250.242', 80))]
# свободен error.qwerty
```

[или](https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/) `pip install python-whois`

```
import whois
for dom in ['ya.ru', 'error.qwerty']:
    details = whois.whois(dom)
    print(f'\n{dom}:\n {details}')

# ya.ru:
#  {
#   "domain_name": "YA.RU",
#   "registrar": "RU-CENTER-RU",
#   "creation_date": "1999-07-12 14:40:22",
#   "expiration_date": "2021-07-31 21:00:00",
#   "name_servers": [
#     "ns1.yandex.ru.",
#     "ns2.yandex.ru."
#   ],
#   "status": "REGISTERED, DELEGATED, VERIFIED",
#   "emails": null,
#   "org": "YANDEX, LLC."
# }

# error.qwerty:
#  {
#   "domain_name": null,
#   "registrar": null,
#   "whois_server": null,
#   "referral_url": null,
#   "updated_date": null,
#   "creation_date": null,
#   "expiration_date": null,
#   "name_servers": null,
#   "status": null,
#   "emails": null,
#   "dnssec": null,
#   "name": null,
#   "org": null,
#   "address": null,
#   "city": null,
#   "state": null,
#   "zipcode": null,
#   "country": null
# }
```

Comment: Способ с getaddrinfo не прокатит, если у занятого домена нет A/AAAA записей